# Floating TOC doesn't work in interactive RMarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have an interactive RMarkdown document. The table-of-contents (TOC) works fine with `rmarkdown::render()`, but doesn't work with `rmarkdown::run()`.

Here is my test code:

````
---
title: "Testing shiny Rmd"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    number_sections: true
    theme: united
    highlight: textmate
runtime: shiny
---

# Section A

This is some text

# Section B

And some more text.

```{r,eval=FALSE}
data(iris)
plot(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Sepal.Width)
```
````

Here is `rmarkdown::render()`

[image]

Here is `rmarkdown::run()`

[image]

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

rmarkdown_1.12
shiny_1.2.0
```

Comment: What web browser did you try?

Comment: I used firefox. After your comment, I also tried in Chrome and it doesn't work.

Comment: Same problem. Did you find the solution at last?

Comment: No solution yet :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the 1.12 version of rmarkdown (as well as the newly published 1.13 version). I encountered the same problem and saw a solution [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rmarkdown-1-12-toc-table-of-contents-is-broken/29911) that solved my issue.

For now install the development version of **rmarkdown** via:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')
```